# How to install new downloaded backend theme in odoo 9

Tags: themes, odoo-9

I have downloaded a theme from odoo **backend** theme market named **artarad_theme_v9**. I tried to install the theme and failed to install.

Now when I googled, I got the response to **update apps module** after changing to **developer mode**. I did that too.

Where should I keep the downloaded folder? Will the theme also be shown in the **app list** itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep your theme folder inside the addons folder. Then you update the App list, search for your theme in the apps list, install it.

Comment: Yeah! since I installed using bitnami the addon folder was different. 

i.e: "/Users/juasoft/Documents/BITNAMI/odoo9/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-9.0rc20160620-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons" Now it worked!

Thanks

Comment: Hi brother, please join the odoo group under stack overflow chat

Comment: There are several "addons" folders:
1. /odoo/custom/addons
2. /odoo/odoo-server/addons
3. /odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons